# Is there any way to remove table row using react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm tired to make a small list where the user can insert rows and clear a row also once the user submits then it should be visible to the same field.

Now I have faced two problems I can't delete an exact row when I clicked on the delete button the row deletes from the last, but I want it should be deleted exact row, that I want.

And another problem with my clear row button, once I clicked on that then it should be clear all rows without three buttons and a table head.

Here is my full code:

```
function Test2() {

  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);

  // Initial states
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isAdd, setAdd] = useState(false);
  const [disable, setDisable] = useState(true);
  const [showConfirm, setShowConfirm] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === "clickaway") {
      return;
    }
    setOpen(false);
  };


  const handleAdd = () => {
    setRows([
      ...rows,
      {
        id: rows.length + 1,
        amount: "",
      },
    ]);
    setAdd(true);
  };

  // Function to handle save
  const handleSave = () => {
    setAdd(!isAdd);
    setRows(rows);
    // console.log("saved : ", rows);
    setDisable(true);
    setOpen(true);
    console.log(rows);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
    setDisable(false);
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...rows];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setRows(list);
  };

  const handleConfirm = () => {
    setShowConfirm(true);
  };


  const handleRemoveClick = (i) => {
    const list = [...rows];
    list.splice(i, 1);
    setRows(list);
    console.log(list);
    setShowConfirm(false);
  };

  // Handle the case of delete confirmation
  // where user click no
  const handleNo = () => {
    setShowConfirm(false);
  };

  const handleClearAll = () => {
    setAdd(false);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ width: 600, margin: "auto" }}>
      <Button onClick={handleAdd}>
        <AddBoxIcon />
        INSERT NEW ROW
      </Button>
      <Button onClick={handleClearAll}>
        <ClearIcon /> CLEAR ROW
      </Button>

      {disable ? (
        <Button disabled align="right" onClick={handleSave}>
          <DoneIcon />
          SUBMIT
        </Button>
      ) : (
        <Button align="right" onClick={handleSave}>
          <DoneIcon />
          SUBMIT
        </Button>
      )}

      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Item name </TableCell>
            <TableCell>Amount</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Action</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>

        <TableBody>
          {rows?.map((row, i) => {
            return (
              <TableRow key={i}>
                {isAdd ? (
                  <TableCell>{`Item ${row.id}`}</TableCell>
                ) : (
                  <TableCell>{`Item ${row.id}`}</TableCell>
                )}
                {isAdd ? (
                  <TableCell align="left">
                    <TextField
                      sx={{
                        width: 100,
                      }}
                      type="number"
                      value={row.amount}
                      name="amount"
                      onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
                    />
                  </TableCell>
                ) : (
                  <TableCell>{row.amount}</TableCell>
                )}

                {isAdd ? (
                  <TableCell>
                    <Button className="mr10" onClick={handleConfirm}>
                      <ClearIcon />
                    </Button>
                  </TableCell>
                ) : (
                  <TableCell>
                    <Button className="mr10" onClick={handleConfirm}>
                      <DeleteOutlineIcon />
                    </Button>
                  </TableCell>
                )}
                {showConfirm && (
                  <div>
                    <Dialog open={showConfirm} onClose={handleNo}>
                      <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
                        {"Confirm Delete"}
                      </DialogTitle>
                      <DialogContent>
                        <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
                          Are you sure to delete
                        </DialogContentText>
                      </DialogContent>
                      <DialogActions>
                        <Button
                          onClick={() => handleRemoveClick(i)}
                          color="primary"
                          autoFocus
                        >
                          Yes
                        </Button>
                        <Button onClick={handleNo} color="primary" autoFocus>
                          No
                        </Button>
                      </DialogActions>
                    </Dialog>
                  </div>
                )}
              </TableRow>
            );
          })}

          <Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={2000} onClose={handleClose}>
            <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="success">
              Record saved successfully!
            </Alert>
          </Snackbar>
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Test2;
```

Comment: `handleRemoveClick` is it your clear row function?

Comment: Yes @Kiddo, but it delete from the last table data.

Comment: `let removeData = rows.filter(el => el.id !== i)` then setRows(removeData) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you're using `i` (index) which will be changed when you add/remove rows, so I'd suggest that you should use `id` (row id) instead

```
handleRemoveClick(row.id)
```

And then modify `handleRemoveClick` to

```
const handleRemoveClick = (rowId) => {
    const list = rows.filter(row => row.id !== rowId); //only remove the selected row
    setRows(list);
    setShowConfirm(false);
};
```

Along with that, you also need to make your row ids unique

```
const generateUniqueId = () => {  
  return 'xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx'.replace(/[x]/g, (c) => {  
        const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);  
        return r.toString(16);  
  });  
}

const handleAdd = () => {
    setRows([
      ...rows,
      {
        id: generateUniqueId(),
        amount: "",
      },
    ]);
    setAdd(true);
};
```

If you don't want to have a unique id generator, you have to modify all row ids

```
const handleRemoveClick = (rowId) => {
    let list = rows.filter(row => row.id !== rowId); //only remove the selected row
    list = list.map((row, index) => ({
       ...row,
       id: index //assign the new index for id
    }));
    setRows(list);
    setShowConfirm(false);
};
```

Side note, this way will re-render all rows that may cause some performance problems if you have too many rows to modify.

---

For your second problem to clear all rows, you should modify `handleClearAll` like below

```
const handleClearAll = () => {
    setAdd(false);
    setRows([]);//clear all rows
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Nick Vu, now I'm clear, actually, where did I mistake

Comment: bro, actually I don't want a unique id generator, I need to value starting from 1. Now I have to face another problem, I can't delete last table row, maybe it happened from `id: rows.length + 1` here, do you have any idea! how to solved

Comment: which event do you use for the last row removal? it's still `handleRemoveClick`? @Alamin

Comment: Yes, it's from 'handleRemoveClick', supposed I added 3 row, after that I can easily remove 2 row, but last one can't remove.

Comment: I added the part you need into my answer, you can try it :D @Alamin